# Problem with jittered data points in geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a boxplot using the following code -

```
ggplot(xray50g, aes(x = Company, y = DefScore, label = Batch, 
                     label2 = PercentPopAff, label3 = AvVertAff, 
                     label4 = EggsPerLitreReceiving)) +
geom_boxplot() +
geom_point(aes(colour = Ploidy), size = 0.5) +
geom_jitter() +
# USE ENVSTATS PACKAGE TO INCLUDE SAMPLE SIZE
stat_n_text(size = 3) +
# INCLUDE MEAN VALUES
stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "point", shape = 4, size = 2, color = "black") +
stat_summary(fun = mean, colour = "black", geom = "text", size = 3, show.legend = FALSE,
           hjust = -0.35, vjust = -0.5, aes( label = round(..y.., digits = 2)))
```

I wanted to spread the data points out a little; however, when I use geom_jitter it seems to blur all the data points together and ruin the chart (see image).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: decrease the size of the points, try ggbeeswarm package. And for more help provide some test data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `width` argument of `geom_jitter` to control how much the points are spread along the x-axis. I'd also recommend making the jittered points transparent (`alpha` argument) and to stop `geom_boxplot` from plotting the outliers with the `outlier.shape` argument (as those points also will be plotted by the jitter layer). Try the following:

```
ggplot(xray50g, aes(x = Company, y = DefScore, label = Batch, 
                     label2 = PercentPopAff, label3 = AvVertAff, 
                     label4 = EggsPerLitreReceiving)) +
geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
geom_jitter(alpha = 0.25, width = 0.1)
```